# Why doesn't my code let me print how many times it's run?

Tags: python, string, printing, integer, counting

So, I know the question is confusing, but hear me out. I'm trying to count how many times my code has run, and I got that, but when I try and implement that into a line of printing code, it tells me it can't print integers. Why?

```
    count = 0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    Current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    start = datetime.time(10)
    end = datetime.time(11)
    while start <= now.time() <= end:
        count+=1
        print("This alarm has gone off + count + "times")
        winsound.PlaySound("C:/Users/gabec/Documents/Audacity/Untitled.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        time.sleep(14) ##The sound is 14 seconds long.
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Is this specific enough?

Comment: No, I see no error traceback at all.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean "error traceback"? Do you mean what my problem was?

Comment: You *could* search for ‘python full error traceback ‘

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using an f-string:

`print(f"This alarm has gone off {count} times")`

Answer (score 0):

You're using incorrect syntax. Try changing into this:

```py
print("This alarm has gone off", count, "times")
```

Even if you include your missing double quote for the string, you cannot add a string (`"This alarm...."`) with an integer (`count`).

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are incorrect: '"this alarm as gone off" + count + "times"'
also, you need to change count from a int (probably not my problem) by typing 'str(count)'
at the start so, (also, I put `int()` at the start just in case it will repeat.)

```
count = 0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    Current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    start = datetime.time(10)
    end = datetime.time(11)
    while start <= now.time() <= end:
        int(count)        
        count+=1
        str(count)
        print("This alarm has gone off + count + "times")
        winsound.PlaySound("C:/Users/gabec/Documents/Audacity/Untitled.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
        time.sleep(14) ##The sound is 14 seconds long.
```

Comment: Ok, first of all thank you for the quote and the count thing. Second, I will try the `str()' Suggestion. Thank you.